# If I stop typing for more than a few seconds the keyboard stops working. Can be briefly fixed by pluggin in a usb device

Tags: windows-10, laptop, keyboard

Alienware x17 laptop running windows 10, all software patches are up to date.

A few seconds to a minute after I boot the lappy up the keyboard stops working. The backlight stays on and the windows key disable key still works but nothing else, not even caps lock.

While the keyboard is working all the keys work. It can be fixed by inserting, or removing, a usb device (only tested memory and a mouse dongle) or closing the lid for a second. The power setting for the lid closing is to do nothing. But it only fixes the keyboard for a few seconds. When the keyboard works again, it unbuffers and prints the first key pressed after it stopped working.

As long as I keep typing, it's okay. But once I stop for more than about 5 seconds, if freezes. Also the cursor stops flashing.

I'm out of ideas.
Thanks.

Comment: Does this also happen with an external keyboard?

Comment: I don't have one, but my mouse installs as a keyboard as well as a mouse and its buttons work. So ... probably? I thought that might be why pluging/unplugging it made it work, but it reacts the same to memory sticks.

Comment: You need to make sure that an external keyboard behaves normally. If you can bring your laptop to someone that has a keyboard so you can test, then we can be sure. If it works correctly with an external keyboard, then the internal keyboard might be defective. It can also be a software problem. You can try booting a linux live or access the BIOS/UEFI and see if the keyboard works there.

Comment: Eternal keyboard works normally. Lappy keyboard works with the UEFI.
I've done a hard reinstall of windows, it didn't help.

Comment: That leaves a driver issue or other setting. You can try a linux livecd. should work okay there too.

Comment: Well, yeah. I guess.  It doesn't really help though. It's not like I hate linux or anything. I just need this lappy running windows.

Comment: Of course. But this test will tell you a lot. If it is all working fine in linux, we rule out hardware. We can then try different drivers in windows for the keyboard, chipset, motherboard, and other things, as well as settings like power management, and other things. By narrowing down that it is indeed something in windows, and not a problem with your hardware, you can also google more effectively.

Comment: I see your point. My friend's comment was, "Oh yeah, I've seen this before - it means you're running the wrong OS". He's the only guy I know who runs a command line on his phone.

I found a "Device Descriptor Request Failed" down in the device manager which I swear wasn't there before. That led me to this -

https://www.dell.com/community/en/conversations/alienware/m17-r4-keyboard-stops-working-unknown-usb-device-device-descriptor-request-failed/647f9b53f4ccf8a8def324fc

Comment: Huh. It's also stopped working in the bios, and plugging in a USB device isn't even momentarily fixing it. I don't think this is a software problem anymore.

Comment: I agree. But it could be as simple as a cable that is loose inside. Pressing the key to access the UEFI could somehow get it to connect. So it may be servicable. Also, laptop keyboards usually are not too expensive to replace. You should verify that it is indeed just the keyboard by using a normal keyboard. That should still work, then you know for sure.